# Python VISA Resource Manager taking a long time to load

Tags: python, resourcemanager, visa, pyvisa

I'm writing scripts to control test equipment.  I've been using the visa library to create handles for the equipment.  Everything has been working fine for a while until recently when I try to open my first resource in my code, it takes about 5 minutes before it finishes.  Once the first equipment is open, the rest are fine.

The code goes something like:

```py
    import visa

    rm = visa.ResourceManager()
    equip1 = rm.open_resource(equip1_address)
    equip2 = rm.open_resource(equip2_address)
```

I stepped through the code and found that it locks up in a functions.py file, in the `open_default_resource_manager(library)` function, at this line:

```
    ret = library.viOpenDefaultRM(byref(session))
```

Here's my "**python -m visa info**":
Machine Details:
   Platform ID:    Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
   Processor:      Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel

Python:
   Implementation: CPython
   Executable:     C:\python27\python.exe
   Version:        2.7.17
   Compiler:       MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)
   Bits:           64bit
   Build:          Oct 19 2019 21:01:17 (#v2.7.17:c2f86d86e6)
   Unicode:        UCS2

PyVISA Version: 1.10.1

Backends:
   ni:
      Version: 1.10.1 (bundled with PyVISA)
      #1: C:\Windows\system32\visa32.dll:
         found by: auto
         bitness: 64
         Vendor: National Instruments
         Impl. Version: 14680064
         Spec. Version: 5243904
      #2: C:\Windows\system32\visa64.dll:
         found by: auto
         bitness: 64
         Vendor: National Instruments
         Impl. Version: 14680064
         Spec. Version: 5243904

For those familiar with Keysight Connection Expert, this is probably related.  When I try to open it, it takes forever to load as well.  Probably also having trouble locating the equipment?

Comment: Faulty device driver? If the device is connected by Ethernet I would check what is going on with WireShark.